# Object.observe() doesn't work native Image object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object.observe

This doesn't work (in chrome 39 on OSX):

```
var x = new Image();
Object.observe(x, function(){console.log('i never run');})
x.src = 'http://www.foo.com';
console.log('has been set: ' + x.src);
```

But this will:

```
var x = new function nonNative(){};
Object.observe(x, function(){console.log('i will run');})
x.src = 'http://www.foo.com';
```

And so will this:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
Object.observe(x, function(){console.log('so will i');})
x.src = 'http://www.foo.com';
```

So the problem isn't related directly to Image being a native constructor (since XMLHttpRequest works as expected) - it seems to be something specific to setting img.src. I can only guess it's because setting an src behaves a lot like a method (in that it causes the request to be made). Is there such a thing in JS as a method which can be called like a property?

Assuming it's not that, does anyone know/can guess if this is desired behaviour of Object.observe (couldn't see anything in [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe)), and if not, where might be the best place for me to report it as a bug?

Comment: It seems to me that the way (new Image()).src is behaving is a lot like how Object.observe() would behave (as in 'something' is detecting the change to the object). Maybe that has something to do with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.src =` is a sort of shorthand for `x.setAttribute('src', ...`, and setting attributes does not trigger `Object.observe`--this is the DOM world, not the JS object world. Attributes on HTMLElements are **not** JS object properties (although sometimes they pretend to be; actually they lurk within the `attributes` property as a `NamedNodeMap`), and JS object properties are what  `Object.observe` observes. You can verify this by setting a non-attribute property on your image, and see the observer function firing.

Setting `src` on `XMLHttpRequest` works because `XMLHttpRequest` is just a plain old JS object and `src` is just a plain old property on it.

If you want to observe attribute changes, you can use mutation observers.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Just out of interest, is it possible to replicate this behaviour in 'normal' JS? e.g. can i write my own object which will call a method when a property is assigned? I have looked at [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) but it seems it isn't widely supported yet.

Comment: I think you are looking for the change type called `'add'` (when the property is assigned for the first time; if it already exists, then change type would be `'update'`).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `src` is not an attribute, it is a defined getter/setter pair, so by assigning it, you are actually calling a function.

Since this is a DOM element, you'd be better off using `MutationObserver`.

```
var x = new Image();
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(){
    console.log('i will run');
});

observer.observe(x, {attributes: true});

x.src = 'http://www.example.com.com'
```